# Why implement 64 base codificatioin instead of other in MIME over smtp protocol?

Tags: smtp, base64

The title says everything.
I would like to ask if there's any place on the internet where i can consult the other "candidates" to MIME protocol.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MIME isn't a protocol, it's really just a format specification.

That said, there are no alternatives for use with SMTP. There are also no open specification alternatives, either (there are proprietary alternatives, but they aren't what the general internet uses - for example, Exchange can/used to(?) use a SOAP-based protocol, GroupWise had its own custom protocol as well, and I'm sure so did Lotus Notes... but they all also support MIME, SMTP, POP3 and IMAP).

Also there's no website that I know of that lists them.